# How to verify if a given CHANNEL ID is right or wrong for Telegram API in python

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-api

How to verify if a given CHANNEL ID is right or wrong for Telegram API in python

And how to get channel details from that channel id

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get informations about a channel using [get_chat](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html?highlight=get_chat#telegram.Bot.get_chat) method in python-telegram-bot